Manipulate and search a value of string before grouping
Suppose I have the following Address_Population table.
Address_Population



Street_Address
City
State
Category
Num_Of_Occupants




1 Abc Street
Augusta
ME
Residential
19


...






1 Xxx Avenue
Augusta
ME
Residential
12


2 Xxx Avenue
Augusta
ME
Commercial
1250


...






256 Xxx Avenue
Augusta
ME
Residential
5


1 Xyz Street
Augusta
ME
Residential
8


...






128 Xyz Street
Augusta
ME
Residential
19


...







What I want to do is, count the number of residential buidling (Category = Residential) for each street that starts with X: e.g. Xxx Avenue, Xyz Street (for above example). In other words, manipulate and search the value of Street_Address column for grouping. If this can not be done in MS Access, then is there a SQL product you can?
Please note that this is not a real data but just to exemplify what I want to do.

Yes, it can be done in Access - and also in just about any other SQL variant.

Address parts should be in separate fields: BuildingNum, AptNum, StreetPrefix, StreetName, StreetType, StreetSuffx.

@June7 I wish it was. However your suggestion requires permission to create the table and populate them at your will.

See simple example
select Street,City,State,Category,sum(Num_Of_Occupants) as totalNum_Of_Occupants
from(
SELECT Address_Population.Id, Address_Population.Street_Address
   , Address_Population.City, Address_Population.State
   , Address_Population.Category, Address_Population.Num_Of_Occupants
   , iif(instr(Street_Address," x")>0
          ,mid(Street_Address,instr(Street_Address," x")+1)
          ,""
     ) AS Street
FROM Address_Population
)
where len(Street)>0
group by Street,City,State,Category;

You can separate address parts to separate fields, or create function for dedicating street name from address and use this function in query.

Regarding the above, for sum of occupants, changing where len(Street)>0  to where len(Street)>0 and Category="Residential" works wondrously. For the number of residential buidling, changing sum(Num_Of_Occupants) as totalNum_Of_Occupants to count(*) as Count works. It would be nice both the sum and count are there with focus on Category="Residential". Thank you very much.

In this case, it seems that Address_Population. in front of each column is unncessary. It works just the same. So I am curious when such notation is needed or becomes an error.

When it is necessary to resolve unambiguity, a prefix is needed. In other case  - no. For example, if you have 2 tables in query clause FROM and booth tables have column Id, prefix as table name is mandatory.
